# Android Why use executePendingBindings in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I have been using lately data bindings and i came across the `executePendingBindings` method. The documentation shows little much about it and i can't understand how it works or when to use it.

A lot of developers use the executePendingBindings inside the onBindViewHolder callback but i don't see any differences myself in recycler when using it  or not.

Can someone explain why its important to use in recycler?? Thanks

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            Customer customer= List.get(position).second;
            ((CustomerViewHolder)holder).binding.setCustomer (customer)

            ((CustomerViewHolder)holder).binding.executePendingBindings();


}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#executependingbindings

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Doing some changes on your binding does not mean that it will have an **immediate** effect on your `View`. Changing things in binding means that you're really scheduling those changes to be applied in the nearest future. This is for many reasons, performance being one of them.

Imagine you've got some complex expressions in your xmls. You don't want to figure out everything related to binding variables before you set all of them. That would be wasting of resources.

You can see more about it in the generated binding java class itself. I suggest you read through it.

Calling `executePendingBindings` means that you're essentially forcing the framework to do everything it needs to do so far on the binding, right at the moment of calling it.

You don't **have to** do it in your Adapter if your case does not require that. Some people are doing that to be sure that everything is properly set on an item before moving on. So e.g. there's no case like the `onBind` being called again before the previous round of bindings was executed... or something similar...

---

EDIT 1:

Also... don't forget that scheduling of executing changes (for the nearest future) is the thing that allows you to `setVariables` on `binding` from threads different than `UI` thread. Because setting a variable does not touch the `View` itself.

---

EDIT 2:

The easiest way to look at the generated java classes is to:

1. Navigate -> File

[image: navigate-file]

2. Type the name of your binding file in UpperCamelCase followed by `Binding` (e.g. if your layout is `activity_main`, type `ActivityMainBinding`)

[image: activity_main_binding]

Comment: So when NOT using executePendingBindings, setting a binding variable sets immediately its value BUT the view it is scheduled to updated in the near future right?

Comment: Is it possible for a view that has been set with executePendingBindings , being overlapped by an old setting of values that has been set without the executePendingBindings ? Because it does it  asnychronously without executePendingBindings .

Comment: No, because the "scheduling" is not a scheduling in the traditional sense of the word. It's more like "marking the binding that something has changed", rather than "applying a change in future". So when you call `executePendingBindings()`, the "marking" from the old code will be overwritten by the new change, and then it will be cleared by the `executePendingBindings` call. So after that call, there will be no "marking" because it has already been handled (by `executeBindings()` which is a consequence of `executePendingBindings()`).

Comment: One last thing. There is also no overlapping when setting a binding twice without the executePendingBindings. For instance, if we set a binding value, and in the next cycle (if the view hasnt been validated yet), if we set again a new binding value, both values actually gonna be executed with the last remainning at the end. Right? Here we dont have the "clearance" that executePendingBindings method does. Thank youu

Comment: No, just the "current" value will be used for executing. So just the one that is currently present when the "cycle" occurs. So when:

1. `setVariable(A)`; 

2. <no bindings execution happens>; 

3. `setVariable(B)`; 

4. <bindings execution occurs>; 

5. just B will be evaluated & applied;

Comment: @Nick I really suggest you look at the generated java class. It will clear a lot of confusion for you.

Comment: Where can i find the generated java class? I have searched here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/c9a5d6f140f732ca0ff279a4b1ee315072e1c422/library/src/main/java/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.java but doesnt tell much.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a thing I should mention. When you call `executePendingBindings()` your list will not be as smooth as without this call. Because executePendingBindings() do the things in the UI thread. So imagine a list with 500 elements. And then, every time you call this method in the UI, You will get "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread".

Comment: How is executing the pending bindings any different than setting the binding values manually?