# Use of binding breaks RecyclerView item layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-binder

I am building an Android app with Kotlin and decided to replace the calls to findViewById and use binding. It all works fine but specifically, when I change an Adapter for a RecyclerView it breaks the item layout.

Original code with findViewById:

```
class WeightListAdapter(val weights: List<WeightWithPictures>, val onWeightItemClickListener: OnWeightItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<WeightListAdapter.WeightHolder>()  {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WeightListAdapter.WeightHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_weight, parent, false)
        return WeightHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WeightListAdapter.WeightHolder, position: Int) {
        val weightWithPictures = weights[position]
        holder.bind(weightWithPictures)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = weights.size

    inner class WeightHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        private lateinit var weight: Weight
        private val weightValueView: TextView = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.weightValue)
        private val weightDateView: TextView = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.weightDate)
        private val weightImageView: ImageView = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.weightImage) as ImageView
```

And this is the layout:

[image]

But then whenever I use binding:

```
class WeightListAdapter(val weights: List<WeightWithPictures>, val onWeightItemClickListener: OnWeightItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<WeightListAdapter.WeightHolder>()  {

    private var _binding: ListItemWeightBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WeightListAdapter.WeightHolder {
        _binding = ListItemWeightBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        val view = binding.root
        return WeightHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WeightListAdapter.WeightHolder, position: Int) {
        val weightWithPictures = weights[position]
        holder.bind(weightWithPictures)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = weights.size

    inner class WeightHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        private lateinit var weight: Weight
        private val weightValueView: TextView = binding.weightValue
        private val weightDateView: TextView = binding.weightDate
        private val weightImageView: ImageView = binding.weightImage
```

The layout breaks:

[image]

Any ideas about what am I doing wrong here? Is it a bug?

P.S - For now, I am just adding the annotation to ignore bindings as [documented here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) for the item view but I would really like to understand what's wrong.

Comment: My answer was completely wrong (because I didn't read properly) but I can give you a tip at least! You can use ``lateinit var binding: ListItemWeightBinding`` to avoid what you're doing with the pair of ``binding`` variables, and keep it non-null without needing to initialise it. You just need to assign a value before you read from it (like you're doing here)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try that, it would be great to clean up the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your binding needs to be inflated in the context of its parent so its root view's layout params will take effect:

```
binding = ListItemWeightBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
```

I think it will also give you problems that you are creating a `binding` property for the Adapter if you try to use it long term. Each ViewHolder holds a distinct view with a distinct binding instance. It's working now because you use it only for the ViewHolder instantiation immediately after setting each instance. But if that's all your intent is, you should just pass the binding to the constructor of your ViewHolder and omit the adapter's property.

By the way, this is the sort of pattern I use for ViewHolders. Less code. Note, it doesn't have to be an `inner` class.

```
class WeightHolder(binding: ListItemWeightBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener {

    fun bind(item: WeightWithPictures) {
        with (binding) {
            // set data for views here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04 the missing parent context was indeed what caused the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Tenfour04, using the same instance of binding is wrong but I believe the root cause of your issue is with the binding logic. with binding, the data is bound to bind with the view but **not immediately**. So your view gets inflated but since the binding happens at a later stage, scheduled to happen in near future, the `item_view` width is shrunk.

So try the following,

```
// oncreate view logic 
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WeightListAdapter.WeightHolder {
        val binding = ListItemWeightBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return WeightHolder(binding)
    }

// onBindViewHolder logic remains the same

// this remains same as suggested by @Tenfour04 but a change in the bind function
 
class WeightHolder(binding: ListItemWeightBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener {

    fun bind(item: WeightWithPictures) {
        with (binding) {
            // set data for views using databindig
            customVariable = item           
            executePendingBindings() // this is important
        }
    }
}

// define the customvariable in your `item_list_view.xml`
        <variable
            name="customVariable"
            type="packagename.WeightWithPictures" />
```

[`executePendingBindings()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#executependingbindings) is the way we force the binding to happen right away and not to schedule it later

Edit:

This answer is from `Databinding` perspective and not `ViewBinding`

Comment: @groo do check out this [stackoverflow-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043412/android-why-use-executependingbindings-in-recyclerview)

Comment: Hi @Sekiro thanks for the tip I was not aware of executePendingBindings(). I did not need it  and I believe we should use it carefully(only if we really need it) because the doc states it should run on the main UI thread which I think it could slow down the rendering if there are too many entries, right?  
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#executependingbindings

Comment: totally, use it whenever required and in recyclerview with databinding its good to force the framework to execute it right away rather than scheduling it and good to know your issue is solved, Happy coding :)

Comment: The OP appears to be using view binding, not data binding.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you sure mate? we cant bind views with data using `view binding`, as far as I know, viewbindind replaces the costly `findViewById` operation

Comment: Not positive, but why would they have created all those properties for the individual views otherwise? The bind method in my suggested code is for manually setting the data for each view.

Comment: `The bind method in my suggested code is for manually setting the data for each view` now it makes sense, my code suggests databinding, where data is bonded to XML directly and not to access individual views to populate with data