# How can I update the UI without skipping frames

Tags: android, kotlin, repository-pattern, android-databinding, android-mvvm

So I am developing and android app in Kotlin with coroutines and no matter what change I make, I still keep getting the message:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

How can I get rid of it. I mean like I am only displaying nine photos... Below is my code

**Model:**

```
data class Food (
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val price: String,
    @Json(name = "img_url") val imgSrcUrl: String,
    val type: String,
    val description: String,
    val average_rating: String,
    val number_of_raters: String,
    val special_price: String
)
data class FoodCategory(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val foods: List<Food>
)
```

**ViewModel:**

```
enum class NetworkStatus {LOADING, DONE, FAILED}

enum class FontFamily (@FontRes val fontRes: Int) {
    POPPINS_BOLD(R.font.poppins_bold),
    POPPINS(R.font.poppins)
}

class FoodOverviewViewModel(private val foodRepository: FoodRepository): ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var foodProducts: List<Food>

    //This is the data that is gonna be exposed to the viewmodel
    //It will be submitted to a ListAdapter
    private val _foodCategory = MutableLiveData<List<FoodCategory>>()
    val foodCategory: LiveData<List<FoodCategory>>
        get() = _foodCategory
    
    //Used to display a progress bar for network status
    private val _status = MutableLiveData<NetworkStatus>()
    val status: LiveData<NetworkStatus>
        get() = _status

    init {
        getOverviewProducts()
    }

    private fun getOverviewProducts() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            _status.postValue(NetworkStatus.LOADING)
            try {
                getUpdatedFood()
                Log.i("getOverviewProducts","I am running on tread: $coroutineContext")
                _status.postValue(NetworkStatus.DONE)

            }catch (e: Exception) {
                _status.postValue(NetworkStatus.FAILED)
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getUpdatedFood() {
        //withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            val limiter = 6 //Number of items I want to get from the server
            val foodCategory = arrayListOf<FoodCategory>()
            Log.i("getUpdatedFood","I am running on tread: $coroutineContext")

            val getRecommended = foodRepository.getRecommendedFood(limiter.toString())
            foodCategory += FoodCategory(id = 0.toString(), title = "Recommended for you", foods = getRecommended)
            
            val getSpecials = foodRepository.getSpecials(limiter.toString())
            foodCategory += FoodCategory(id = 1.toString(), title = "Specials", foods = getSpecials)

            _foodCategory.postValue(foodCategory)
        //}
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
class FoodRepository {

    suspend fun getRecommendedFood(limiter: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Log.i("Resp-getRecommended","I am running on tread: $coroutineContext")
        return@withContext ProductApi.retrofitService.getRecommended(limiter)
    }
    suspend fun getSpecials(limiter: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Log.i("Resp-getSpecials","I am running on tread: $coroutineContext")
        return@withContext ProductApi.retrofitService.getSpecials(limiter)
    }
}
```

**BindingAdapters:**

```
//Load image using Glide (in Food item recycleview)
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun bindImage(imgView: ImageView , imgUrl: String?) {
    imgUrl?.let {
        val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("http").build()
        Glide.with(imgView.context)
            .load(imgUri)
            .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image))
            .into(imgView)
    }
}

//set raters count (in Food item recycleview)
@BindingAdapter("ratersCount")
fun bindText(txtView: TextView, number_of_raters: String?) {
    number_of_raters?.let {
        val ratersCount = "(${number_of_raters})"
        txtView.text = ratersCount
    }
}

//update the progressbar visibilty (in outer-parent recycleview) 
@BindingAdapter("updateStatus")
fun ProgressBar.updateStatus(status: NetworkStatus?) {
    visibility = when (status) {
        NetworkStatus.LOADING -> View.VISIBLE
        NetworkStatus.DONE -> View.GONE
        else -> View.GONE
    }
}

//Hide or view an imageview based in the network Status. When network Error, an error image
//will show (in outer-parent recycleview)
@BindingAdapter("setNoInternet")
fun ImageView.setNoInternet(status: NetworkStatus?) {
    when(status) {
        NetworkStatus.LOADING -> {
            visibility = View.GONE
        }
        NetworkStatus.DONE -> {
            visibility = View.GONE
        }
        NetworkStatus.FAILED -> {
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
            setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_connection_error)
        }
    }
}

//Submit the list of FoodCatergory item to the outer-parent recycleview
@BindingAdapter("listData")
fun bindRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<FoodCategory>?) {
    (recyclerView.adapter as FoodCategoryAdapter).submitList(data)
}

//Submit list the the Food item recyclew view (child recycleView)
@BindingAdapter("setProducts")
fun RecyclerView.setProducts(foods: List<Food>?) {
    if (foods != null) {
        val foodAdapter = FoodItemAdapter()
        foodAdapter.submitList(foods)

        adapter = foodAdapter
    }
}
```

I have a Recycleview of Food Item and a Recycleview Pool of FoodCategory. If I comment out
`_foodCategory.postValue(foodCategory)` 
in **ViewModel: getUpdatedFood()** than I do not get the message. However, when I submit the list to the outer recycleview (The one the hold the viewpool), than I get this answer. Please help. I been stuck on it for a while tryna get rid of that message.

Thank you..

***Updated***
Below is the adapeters and its view holders

***FoodItem layout***

```
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
                name="foodItem"
                type="com.example.e_commerceapp.models.Food"/>
        <variable
                name="font"
                type="com.example.e_commerceapp.products.overview.FontFamily"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_item_main_layout"
            android:background="@drawable/search_background"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/burger_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                />
<!--        app:imageUrl="@{foodItem.imgSrcUrl}"-->

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/burger_title"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#B4000000"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/burger_image"
                android:text="@{foodItem.name}"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/burger_title"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/burger_price"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/special_price"
                android:textColor="#D0000000"/>

<!--                app:price="@{foodItem.price}"-->
<!--                app:specialPrice="@{foodItem.special_price}"-->
<!--                app:fontRes="@{foodItem.special ? font.POPPINS : font.POPPINS_BOLD}"-->


        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/burger_title"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/special_price"
                android:textColor="#D0000000"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"/>
<!--        app:setSpecialPrice="@{foodItem.special_price}"-->


        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/burger_price"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_24"
                android:visibility="@{foodItem.hasRating ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
                android:id="@+id/rating_star"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="@{foodItem.hasRating ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
                android:id="@+id/rating_count"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/burger_price"
                android:text="@{foodItem.average_rating}"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/rating_star"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/number_of_raters"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="@{foodItem.hasRating ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/rating_count"
                app:ratersCount="@{foodItem.number_of_raters}"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/burger_price"/>

        <ImageView android:layout_width="20dp"
                   android:layout_height="20dp"
                   android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

***FoodItem Adapter***

```
class FoodItemAdapter: ListAdapter<Food ,
        FoodItemAdapter.ItemFoodViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup , viewType: Int): ItemFoodViewHolder {
        return ItemFoodViewHolder(
            FoodItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemFoodViewHolder , position: Int) {
        val currentFood = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentFood)
    }

    class ItemFoodViewHolder(private var binding: FoodItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(food: Food) {
            binding.foodItem = food
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

    object DiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Food>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Food , newItem: Food): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Food , newItem: Food): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }
    }
}
```

***FoodCategory layout***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
                name="foodCategory"
                type="com.example.e_commerceapp.models.FoodCategory"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/category_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@{foodCategory.title}"
                android:textColor="#2B2A2A"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/nestedRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                app:setProducts="@{foodCategory.foods}"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/category_title"
                tools:itemCount="4"
                tools:listitem="@layout/food_item"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

***FoodCategory Adapter***

```
class FoodCategoryAdapter: ListAdapter<FoodCategory,
        FoodCategoryAdapter.CategoryFoodViewHolder>(Companion) {

    private val viewPool = RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup , viewType: Int): CategoryFoodViewHolder {
        return CategoryFoodViewHolder(FoodCategoryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryFoodViewHolder , position: Int) {
        val currentFoodCategory = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentFoodCategory)
    }


    inner class CategoryFoodViewHolder(private var binding: FoodCategoryBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(currentFoodCategory: FoodCategory?) {
            binding.foodCategory = currentFoodCategory
            binding.nestedRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool)
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

    companion object: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<FoodCategory>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: FoodCategory , newItem: FoodCategory): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: FoodCategory, newItem: FoodCategory): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }
    }
}
```

***The parent recycleView***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".products.overview.FoodOverviewFragment">
    <data>
        <variable
                name="foodOverview"
                type="com.example.e_commerceapp.products.overview.FoodOverviewViewModel"/>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/logo_and_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/compony_logo_and_name"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/notifications"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_notifications_24"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                    android:paddingStart="20dp"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/search_background"
                    android:layout_below="@id/logo_and_name"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/search_text"
                    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
                    app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:updateStatus="@{foodOverview.status}"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/relative_layout"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/progressbar"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/relative_layout"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/noInternetImage"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/foodCategory"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                tools:itemCount="4"
                tools:listitem="@layout/food_category"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:listData="@{foodOverview.foodCategory}"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/relative_layout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Do you network-related tasks in the IO thread and update tasksin the main thread.. So if you have to fetch the image do it in Dispatchers.IO and then update it in withContext(Dispatchers. Main)

Comment: I commented out the network operations and added some data manullay just to see of it was the network load. But even after that, I still got the same message. I think when I submit the list of data, the main thread does all the work like setting the image, the name, description, rearranging, etc. How can I do that then in the background?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "outer RecyclerView" and "child RecyclerView"? That sounds very suspect. If you don't handle RecyclerViews carefully they can get very sluggish initial rendering. Can you post your adapter code and also how you set up your views? The problem likely has nothing to do with the code you've already posted. For example: if you use `wrap_content` any other of those RecyclerViews you'll be instantiating all your Views at once, which is slow. And nested RecyclerViews in the same direction could also cause problems. You can confirm this by just emitting dummy data.

Comment: @BrianYencho By that I mean a nested recycleView.. I updated my question and added the adapters and its layouts

Comment: @WesleyMentoor so did you find and fix the ultimate source of the problem?

Comment: @BrianYencho Yes, I did. Thank you. I removed the "executePendingBindings" calls as you have mentioned below. Thank you again. It took me like forever tryna solve that problem....

Comment: @WesleyMentoor Ah cool, I'm glad that solved your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The skipping frames likely has nothing to do with the code you posted: it sounds like a misconfiguration of RecyclerViews / Adapters to me. You'll need to post that code for it be more clear though.

However, even though what you posted likely isn't the culprit you can still optimize the coroutines code you have:

```
class FoodOverviewViewModel(private val foodRepository: FoodRepository): ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var foodProducts: List<Food>

    private val _foodCategory = MutableLiveData<List<FoodCategory>>()
    val foodCategory: LiveData<List<FoodCategory>>
        get() = _foodCategory
    
    private val _status = MutableLiveData<NetworkStatus>()
    val status: LiveData<NetworkStatus>
        get() = _status

    init {
        getOverviewProducts()
    }

    private fun getOverviewProducts() {
        viewModelScope.launch { // <------- Don't apply a custom scope here
            _status.value = NetworkStatus.LOADING // <--- Don't call "postValue" here
            try {
                val food = getUpdatedFood() // <------ This is already using a background dispatcher
                _foodCategory.value = food // <------- Emit this value here
                _status.value = NetworkStatus.DONE
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _status.value = NetworkStatus.FAILED
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getUpdatedFood(): List<FoodCategory> { // <---- Return a value here
        val limiter = 6 //Number of items I want to get from the server
        val foodCategory = arrayListOf<FoodCategory>()
        Log.i("getUpdatedFood","I am running on tread: $coroutineContext")

        val getRecommended = foodRepository.getRecommendedFood(limiter.toString())
            foodCategory += FoodCategory(id = 0.toString(), title = "Recommended for you", foods = getRecommended)
            
        val getSpecials = foodRepository.getSpecials(limiter.toString())
        foodCategory += FoodCategory(id = 1.toString(), title = "Specials", foods = getSpecials)
        return foodCategories
    }
}
```

The key ideas here:

- Use `viewModelScope.launch { ... }` rather than applying a scope. You want everything in there that is *not* a coroutine to run on the main thread. See, for example, https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#main-safe
- Return a value from `getUpdatedFood` so you can just update the `_foodCategory` value on the main thread in the `viewModelScope`

Comment: I updated my code and added the adapters and its layouts

Comment: OK thanks. So first I'd say that one suspicious thing is that you are creating a new adapter each time you call `RecyclerView.setProducts`. You should find a way to ensure there is only ever one adapter created per view. That being said, I don't think that's necessarily your problem. I think the fact that you have a nested RecyclerView in *each item* might be an issue no matter what you do. The best I can say is that for testing you can keep your structure the same but strip out as much from the UI as possible and see if you still get the error. It may be unavoidable with your setup.

Comment: You can also try completely skipping the use of databinding (which I wouldn't recommend anyway) and just updating view properties normally. It's possible that all the binding and rebinding going on introduces some performance hit. At minimum, I'd say you should experiment with removing all the "executePendingBindings" calls and see what happens. Those calls likely aren't necessary and might actually be a big source of the problem. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53868017/5635880

Comment: Finally, if that doesn't work, you should actually just go ahead and do some profiling to actually measure what the issue is: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler